# MySQL before start of resultset

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to get the personID from one table and use it in the second table, and the print each column value from 
the second table, however I am getting an the error `column index out of range, 3 < 1`.  The order table consist of 3 columns.

```
public void getPersonsOrders(String firstName){
    Connection con = connect();                                                                                             
    try{
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        s.executeUpdate("use stl;");
        ResultSet rs1 = s.executeQuery("select personID from person where first_name = " +"'"+firstName+"'"+";");       //get persons ID no.
        rs1.next();
        ResultSet rs2 = s.executeQuery("select * from orderr where personID = "+rs1.getInt(3)+";");             //use ID no. to           
        for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){                                                                             //retrive order
            System.out.println(rs2.getInt(i));
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("3" +e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: `rs1.getInt(3)` - there is only one column in `rs1` (with index 1)

Comment: Take a look at SQL JOINs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one column returned in `rs1`, therefore you should use `rs1.getInt(1)`.

On the other hand, this should easily be solved using a join:

```
SELECT o.* FROM order o
LEFT JOIN person p
ON p.personID = o.personID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rs1 = s.executeQuery("select personID from person where first_name = "+"'"+firstName+"'"+";");
```

The above code will yield a result containing only one column.Use this to make it error free.

```
ResultSet rs2 = s.executeQuery("select * from orderr where personID = "+rs1.getInt(3)+";");            //use ID no. to           
for(int i = 1; i <= 1; i++){ //retrive order
     System.out.println(rs2.getInt(i));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues I'll like to mention to assist in writing better code:
1: if firstName contains a single quote, your sql statement will fail (You'll have a single quote in firstrName, which itself is in single quotes). You either need to convert any occurrences of single quote in firstName to two single quotes, or use preparedStatements.
2: Its better to use terms such as getInt("personID") rather than getInt(1) so its easier to read.
3: We typically use if(rs1.next()){} (expecting one result) or while(rs1.next()){} (expecting more than one result) instead of rs1.next().
4: We typcially close the connection, preparedStatement, and resultSet in the reverse order they are declared in the finally  block of a try/catch/finally block (checking to see if they are null before closing them).